# Check if Day is Saturday or Sunday

Tags: scala

I'm looking to do a `difference between 2 date in scala`. These 2 date are should not saturday not sunday.
 I did a scala function to test if the day if Saturday or Sunday:

I edited my question, this is my code to test if a day is saturday or sunday.
I should use it using tow dates : start_date and finish_date, because after this operation I'll do the difference between these tow dates.
My function jourouvree took one parameter, not a dates.
How can I modify my code to pass the tow dates.

Comment: `def jourOuvree(d1: Date, d2: Date, Int: n) = for (i <- 1 to n)` last `n` is not defined

Comment: See the difference between the definition of the arguments: `d1: Date` works and `Int: n` doesn't - because the name should come first - `name: Type`, i.e. `n: Int`

Comment: How can I change my code to pass tow dates in parameter of the function
because, here in my code it give me the number of month = 2 not 3 and day = 26

Comment: I can't get your code to compile, but here are some things to note: jourOuvree has an incorrect argument, `Int: n`. Should be `n: Int`. Your `var calendar` isn't visible to your jourOuvree method as it is only local to the main method here. `calendar.SATURDAY` isn't a thing - you might mean `Calendar.SATURDAY`. `java.util.Calendar` starts on Sunday, so Monday is day 2, Wednesday is day 4, etc. `java.util.Calendar.MONTH` is zero-indexed, so January is month 0. I don't know what your `get`s are meant to do but it only takes one parameter, not two. Please update your Q with code which compiles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question by a code compile well. Can you read it to help me please.

Answer (score 2):

Check if Day is Saturday or Sunday:

```
import java.time.{LocalDate, DayOfWeek}

def isWeekend(day: LocalDate) =
  day.getDayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY ||
    day.getDayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 datetime api:

```
import java.time._
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val formatter =  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
//Assume d2,d2 themselves are not weekend days
def jourOuvree(sd1:String, sd2:String): Unit = {
    val d1 = LocalDateTime.parse(sd1, formatter)
    val d2 = LocalDateTime.parse(sd2, formatter)
    //return if d1 is not earlier than d2. TODO: handle what to be done
    if(d2.isAfter(d1) == false) return
    var (days, dayCtr) = (1, 1)
    while(d1.plusDays(dayCtr).isBefore(d2)){
        dayCtr+=1
        val dow = d1.plusDays(dayCtr).getDayOfWeek()
        if(!dow.equals(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY) && !dow.equals(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY))
            days+=1
    }
    println(days)
}
```

Invoke as below:

```
jourOuvree("2011-03-31 07:55:00", "2011-04-06 15:41:00")
```

You get `5` printed.

NOTE: The code doesn't handle exceptions in parsing.
Also, there may be other requirement fine points, for which you are the best judge to make required changes.